# How do I get this div to cover flash control (jw player)?

Tags: html, css, flash, jwplayer

Ive got a flash player (jw)...

And I used some downloaded code to make a drop down menu.

In firefox the drop down menu covers the jw Player but in other browsers it shows up behind the player:

[a screen shot of the problem](http://img718.imageshack.us/i/layersv.jpg/)

Here is a screen shot of the code and css in IE developer tools:

[a screen of the html and css](http://img189.imageshack.us/i/layerscode.jpg/)

As you can see from the second image I have set the z-index to 9999 but it doesnt work and I have no idea how to force the div to display over the flash control in all browsers...

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

as a child element to your `object` tag should fix it. Or, the `wmode="transparent"` parameter, if you're using an `embed` tag.